# How to create a parameterized query?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odp.net

I've been stuck with this problem for a while and have gone through several tutorials without success.

How do you use paramaterized queries in C# with the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` rather than the old `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`?

The code I have tried is:

```
string query = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM @table WHERE @custNM = '@nm'";

OracleCommand mySearch = new OracleCommand(query, newConn);
mySearch.Prepare();

mySearch.Parameters.Add("@table", "cust");
mySearch.Parameters.Add("@custNM", "nm");
mySearch.Parameters.Add("@nm", "SAM");
```

I have also tried it without the `mySearch.Prepare` section and wit : instead of `@` and without the `@` prefixing the query string. Another thing I tried was removing the `@`/`:` at the start of the `Add` string e.g.

```
mySearch.Parameters.Add("nm", "SAM");
```

My end goal is to use variables to pass values instead of just string text for the statement, if that's easier to do.

Comment: object identifiers cannot be used as paramaters

Comment: Another common "gotcha"to be aware of is that ODP.NET defaults to "bind by position" meaning it does not care what names you are using for the parameters, it only cares in which order you "Add" them. If you want bindbyname instead, there is a property for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should use `:` as the parameter identifier instead of `@`, which is commonly used by SQL Server.

Second, You can't supply the table name or field names using parameters. It should either be hard-coded or written using dynamic SQL.

Third, you shouldn't escape parameters. They don't need that.

The best thing possible now is this:

```
string query = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM cust WHERE nm = :nm";

OracleCommand mySearch = new OracleCommand(query, newConn);
mySearch.Parameters.Add(":nm", "SAM");
```

Comment: In regards to your first sentence, is `:` simply just "the Oracle way", or is there an actual difference?